# xamarin.android an error occurred when installing

Tags: android, .net, installation, xamarin

I've tried to update Windows and downloaded .NET Framework 4.5. I've got Windows 7 Professional x32 and also Visual C# Express 2010 installed.

```
An error has occurred
```

Errors have ocurred 
Please attach te installation log if you contact about this error, thank you!
installation of archive mono-android-4.8.00013.msi failed with exception
Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
 CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , InstallationArchiveHandler , String , Object )
  Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
  Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.MonoAndroidSdkSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
  WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()

Comment: This is just me trowing stabs in the air, but you did got Elevated Privileges, I mean UAC, the thing asking you for administrative permissions.

Comment: i shutted my uac down but still same error

Comment: what you reccomends me to do than?,i also try to run as administrator...

Comment: this is the exceptions http://imageshack.us/a/img341/4122/yif.png

Comment: Could you please, instead copying and pasting, the content of the box?

Comment: look at the image on the comment bro

Comment: That's exactly the problem, I can't read the content from left to right and the code up to down. Better consider clicking where it says "View installation log" and post it on some Pastebin service to take a complete look at the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the exact same issue this last weekend when I tried to update my Xamarin setup. No matter how many times I tried it always failed with the exact messages which you have got. I guess it a bug in the setup file.

Anyways, I was able to resolve the issue by manually installing Monodroid. You will find the downloaded file in your "%temp%" directory. Look for Xamarin folder and install the msi directly and it will go through without any issues.

Comment: Running the file in TEMP still didn't work for me. I've check Xamarin forums, but there a guy always answered "Please contact support@xamarin.com" ... grrr. Finally I found URL for older version of mono-android: http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.6.00049.msi